# The custom domain wont connect to website (evennode)

Tags: node.js, dns, evennode

I've purchased a hosting service on evennode (for nodejs application), and have a domain at hostinger.
I've followed the instruction from both evennode and hostinger on how to set it up, stating that i have to add custom domains in textarea on evennode in settings, and to add cname record on hostinger.
The cname is set up as www and points to evennode app (evennode-name.eu-4.evennode.com). It's almost been 48 hours and nothing is progressing. Did I do something wrong? The hostinger support is not very helpful.

Comment: Can you explain "nothing is progressing" with more technical detail?

Comment: Well, what I've meant is that I've been checking up on whatsmydns.net. The www.domain.com for CNAME is actually fully established, but the root is not anywhere. The first 24 hours were set to root instead of www, but neither seem to work. Are there other technical details I could provide?

Comment: What does "the root is not anywhere" mean? It's really hard to debug this problem remotely with little information. Generally you can't `CNAME` a whole domain, that's a lesser-used `ANAME` quasi-record.

Comment: I meant it would not show green checkmark anywhere on the map. The CNAME idea was not mine, it was by instruction of the node hosting service https://www.evennode.com/docs/custom-domains. There is no nameserver or IP given, they say just add CNAME record, so I'm pretty confused

Comment: For an "apex" record on your domain you can't use CNAME. Specify the A address of your server instance. This process likely hews close to what [GitHub recommends for GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site).